# Multisite with some shared content and some different content

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I need to create 7 magazine sites with different themes but some content should be shared (like some common pages, some pictures etc).

There should be a common control panel for all websitea so that my customer can upload data on all websites from the same panel. The same content is required because the customer will upload articles on one and it should publish on all site.

I have already setup two demo site with different database on one hosting place and single Drupal installation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want a multi-site at all by the sounds of it. You're looking for [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain)

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for
>   running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a
>   single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content,
>   and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique

In fact, the ORIGINAL use case for Domain Access was for magazine sites ([from the documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/domain)), so it should fit your needs perfectly!

Comment: Thank you very much..I am checking Domain Access and I think it will be very helpful.

Comment: I installed Domain Access successfully. I have two different domain name both are pointing to same folder where Drupal is installed. Both domain are added in Domain access. Both domain name are showing same content. It looks that Domain Access is not differentiating between both domains. I am using Godaddy Linux server. Do I need to do any setting on DNS?